# Can I make a dynamic interface in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have created a custom class (DynamicItem) that inherits the DynamicObject class and this works great with the dynamic keyword. The DynamicItem also implements and interface because I know that some of the properties will always occur, my test for this looks like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void InterfaceTest()
    {
        //Assign
        Item item = _db.GetItem(TargetPath);          

        dynamic d = new DynamicItem(item);
        IDynamicItem i = d as IDynamicItem;


        //Act
        string result = d.Title;
        string path = i.Path;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("awesome", result);
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Path, path);
    }
```

The "Title" property is not defined on the interface and is dynamically invoked. The "Path" property is defined on the interface.

This test passes and everything works as you would expect. The thing that annoys me is that I have to do a cast from the dynamic to the interface. What I would like to be able to do is just use the interface:

```
    [Test]
    public void InterfaceTest()
    {
        //Assign
        Item item = _db.GetItem(TargetPath);          

        IDynamicItem d = new DynamicItem(item);


        //Act
        string result = d.Title;
        string path = d.Path;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("awesome", result);
        Assert.AreEqual(item.Path, path);
    }
```

However if I do this the compiler complains because it can't find the "Title" property on the interface. Is there a way of flagging the interface as being dynamic at the same time as being an interface for the compiler?

Comment: It is an incredibly rare scenario that you should need to remove the Type-safety of C# by using the dynamic keyword.  Why are you using it?

Comment: An interface is a pre-defined contract of methods and properties that components know ahead of time. A dynamic object is the exact opposite of that.

Comment: I am in integrating with a CMS which has unknown fields. It would be great to be able to have the know item properties on the interface but then allow the user access to their custom fields via the dynamic type.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot create a dynamic interface. An [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) is a pre-defined set of methods and properties that all components using / implementing the interface know about ahead of run-time. If a component implements an interface, it gives a guarantee that methods / properties of the interface will be available to users of the component. It also makes it possible to replace one component with another one, as long as the new one implements the same interface.

A dynamic object, on the other hand, has nothing pre-defined about it - its layout is generated at run-time, based on conditions that may change over time. If a function returns a dynamic object, it may return different dynamic objects (with different properties) if you call it multiple times. When a caller calls such a function, there's no guarantee about the layout of the returned object. This is the opposite of interfaces.

As @SteveLillis commented, it's very rare that you actually need a dynamic object. In most situations, you can just use a `Dictionary<string, object>` (or something similar along those lines) and get a more type-safe approach that's less confusing to follow for someone else. In many years of programming, I only needed to use the `dynamic` keyword 2 or 3 times - in all other situations, a properly chosen data structure was sufficient - statically typed and type-safe (well, to some extent).

Here's one possible example of doing what you're trying to do:

```
public interface IMyDynamicItem
{
    string SomeItemName { get; set; }

    object this[int nFieldIndex] { get; set; }

    object this[string sFieldName] { get; set; }

    IList<string> FieldNames { get; }
}

public class MyDynamicItem : IMyDynamicItem
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> m_oFields = 
        new Dictionary<string, object> ();

    public string SomeItemName { get; set; }

    public object this[int nFieldIndex]
    {
        get
        {
            string sFieldName = FieldNames[nFieldIndex];

            return ( m_oFields[sFieldName] );
        }
        set
        {
            string sFieldName = FieldNames[nFieldIndex];

            m_oFields[sFieldName] = value;
        }
    }

    public object this[string sFieldName]
    {
        get
        {
            return ( m_oFields[sFieldName] );
        }
        set
        {
            m_oFields[sFieldName] = value;
        }
    }

    public IList<string> FieldNames
    {
        get
        {
            return ( new List<string> ( m_oFields.Keys ) );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but this would give you roughly what you're trying to achieve but it's less than ideal - the true interface members can be accessed through dot notation (that is, `oItem.SomeItemName`) but the dynamic members can only be accessed through an indexer notation (`oItem[2]` or `oItem["SomeField"]`).

It'd be possible to add in the interface members into the internal dictionary so that all members can be looked up through the indexer notation - I personally feel that approach dirty. In such a scenario, I'd probably just separate out the dynamic fields into a true dictionary and not try to maintain the illusion that those fields are somehow part of an interface - it may be more typing but the code is a lot cleaner.

Comment: It seems that the OP is looking for some sort of "semi-dynamic" mechanism, which as you and others suggest would best be accomplished with a `Dictionary` property to hold the extra unknown properties. Perhaps give a super slim example of a class that contains a couple well-defined properties plus a dictionary, and an example of how it would be used?

Comment: @ean5533 Keep in mind, though, that the OP won't be able to do what he tried in his snippet: I can create an interface with some static members and dictionary-like lookup methods but then the OP won't be able to access the dictionary portion using dot notation.

Comment: Agreed. I see two options that get close to what the OP wants: 1) `myObject.KnownProp` and `myObject.UnknownProps["key1"]`. Not ideal. 2) Write an indexer, so that you can do `myObject.KnownProp` and `myObject["key1"]`. Better, but still not ideal.

Comment: @ean5533 I added a code sample. Thanks for the suggestion.